# Nested form group can't find elements

Tags: angular

I have a nested form group I've setup as follows:

```
this.detailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    'eventDates': [
        this.formBuilder.group({
            'startDate': [
                this.event.start
            ],
```

and the HTML looks like

```
<form *ngIf="detailsForm" [formGroup]="detailsForm" (submit)="saveDetails()">
    <div formGroupName="eventDates">
        <div class="row">
            <label>Event Start</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <mat-form-field class="datepicker">
                <input matInput [matDatepicker]="eventStartDate" formControlName="startDate">
```

But for reasons I can't figure out why I get this error: `Cannot find control with path: 'eventDates -> startDate`. The form worked before I had a nested form group, and changing the form element names didn't seem to help. I'm not sure what in my structure is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax:

```typescript
this.formBuilder.group({
  'eventDates': [something]
})
```

creates `FormGroup` with `eventDates` control that has value `something`

I guess you're looking for:

```typescript
this.formBuilder.group({
  'eventDates': this.formBuilder.group(
       {
       'startDate': ['someValue']
       }, {
         validator: syncValidator, // validator for eventDates group
         asyncValidator: asyncValidator // async validator for eventDates group
       }
   )
})
```

Comment: Sorry, how is that different from what I have? I have it in an array because I'm putting a validator on the `eventDates` form group, but otherwise my syntax is the same?

Comment: Just tried it without the array, leaving the same syntax you provided, and it still gives the same error.

Comment: If you want to provide validator to formGroup then you should use the syntax like https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ffc6e199bf92ee1e05a8814f21de2c1aa19a7184/packages/forms/test/form_builder_spec.ts#L82 Note extra parameters

Comment: So I copied what you have in that run into my code, and it still gives the error. Obv that means it's something else, but I cannot figure out what.

Comment: Please create stackblitz example. Obv you're doing something wrong

Comment: No idea what I've done wrong. I literally just copied my code to a stack blitz, minus the material stuff, and it works.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awsbyc?file=app/form-field-overview-example.html

Comment: With datepicker https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awsbyc?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.html

Comment: Figured it out. Your answer wasn't exactly correct, but pointed me in the right direction. I had things in the wrong braces, but no way to tell it from what I provided. As a note, you can pass a validator as the second parameter to `formbuilder.group` without the array. The third element can be an async validator, just like with a form control.

Comment: What's wrong with my answer? I showed example where you can provide validator in the second parameter